# Forgot to reserve a seat on Norwegian Air. Do I need to check-in in person?

Tags: europe, seating, norwegian-air-shuttle

I got my boarding passes but noticed that I had forgotten to make seats reservations, on the website it says that if I don't choose my seats then I will be assigned seats on the day of the departure. Does this means that I have to get there a bit earlier and go check-in in person? Or just carry my boarding pass and head straight to the gate?

Comment: is this really a boarding pass that you have or rather a booking confirmation? in any case, yes, you'll get assigned a seat automatically BUT, there could be situations where you'll not, if there is overbooking for instance. So I would suggest you to get to the airport a bit in advance to get a confirmation of your seat assignment.

Comment: It is indeed a boarding pass, but since the flight is tomorrow I still didn't get a seat assigned.

Comment: Try to get there a bit early, just to be on the safe side :)

Comment: With some airlines, you can go through the check in process even after you're checked in, and get (or change) seats and print new boarding passes.  Have you tried this?

Comment: How did you sort it out?

Answer (score 4):

When we book Norwegian, we don't book seats as it's cheaper. 
I scan my barcode at the airport check-in kiosk and it prints for me my boarding pass with a seat mentioned on it.

You can also check-in online within 24 hours before the flight.

Get your barcode with:

1. **SMS** If you used you mention your phone number, 2 hours before your flight you will get a message with a link, press on link and get your barcode.
2. **Norwegian Mobile app** Login to your app on a phone or tablet and get barcode there.
3. **Norwegian Web-site** You can also find your barcode in "My travel".

More information you can find here:
https://www.norwegian.com/en/travel-info/check-in-and-boarding/online-check-in/ and here:
https://www.norwegian.com/uk/travel-info/check-in-and-boarding/direct-to-gate/

> If you're flying with just hand baggage from a Nordic country to another European destination (not UK), you can show your travel document on your smartphone at security screening and go directly to your gate.